# How to remove vertical space before list in table cell?

Tags: tables, spacing, koma-script, paralist

I want to get very compact lists in table cells, but there is still a vertical space before the first list item (see screenshot below). How can I remove this vertical space?

[image: example screenshot]

#### LaTeX code for example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{paralist}

\newenvironment{tcitem}{%
  \setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}{1em}%
  \vspace{-\topsep}%
  \compactitem[-]
}{\raggedright
  \vspace*{-\ht\strutbox}%
  \endcompactitem
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX }
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
\midrule
Text in Col 1 
& \begin{tcitem}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{tcitem}
& \begin{tcitem}
\item Forth item
\item Fifth item
\item Sixth item
\item Seventh item
\end{tcitem}
\\ 
\midrule
Text in second row & no items, no vertical space & no items, no vertical space  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

### File List

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (type area)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
tabularx.sty    2014/10/28 v2.10 `tabularx' package (DPC)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
paralist.sty    2013/06/09 v2.4 Extended list environments
 ***********
```

Comment: I get no vertical space when compiling your code (on a TL2014, last updated a few weeks ago).

Comment: @jfbu: thanks a lot. So I'll make a backup and update my TeXLive 2014.

Comment: The main dates from `\listfiles` are `2015/02/07 v3.16` (KOMA-Script document class), `booktabs.sty 2005/04/14` `v1.61803`, and `array.sty` `2014/10/28 v2.4c` and `longtable.sty` `2014/10/28 v4.11` and `tabularx.sty`    `2014/10/28 v2.10`and `paralist.sty` `2013/06/09 v2.4`.

Comment: @jfbu: thanks! how/where did you find those versions/dates information?

Comment: you only need to add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then check the log file after compilation for the list which will start with ` *File List*` and end with ` ***********`

Comment: @jfbu thanks - cool trick :-) - so it seems to be the KOMA-Script version v3.14 which is outdated in my setup.

Comment: yes your file list differs from mine only for the various KOMA-script packages.

Comment: confirmed about KOMA 3.14. But with the earlier KOMA 3.12, the space doesn't show either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space doesn't show with current `KOMA 3.16` files, and it doesn't show either with the latest KOMA from TL2013 (`KOMA 3.12`). It shows with `KOMA 3.14`.